# disable the last row

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have this table in PostgreSQL:

```
 appid |               appname               | apptype | creationtime | createdby | display
-------+-------------------------------------+---------+--------------+-----------+---------
     0 | Custom                              |      -1 |              |           | t
  1000 | Performance/Resource                |      -2 |              |           | t
  2000 | PING                                |       0 |              |           | t
  2001 | HTTP                                |       0 |              |           | t
  2002 | HTTPS                               |       0 |              |           | t
  2003 | FTP                                 |       0 |              |           | t
  2004 | LDAP                                |       0 |              |           | t
  2005 | IMAP                                |       0 |              |           | t
  2006 | POP                                 |       0 |              |           | t
  2007 | SMTP                                |       0 |              |           | t
  2008 | DNS                                 |       0 |              |           | t
  2009 | NFS                                 |       0 |              |           | t
  2010 | NTP                                 |       0 |              |           | t
  2011 | SSH                                 |       0 |              |           | t
  2012 | TCP                                 |       0 |              |           | t
  2013 | TELNET                              |       0 |              |           | t
  3000 | Generic Mail (RTT)                  |       3 |              |           | t
  3001 | Apache Tomcat                       |       2 |              |           | t
  3002 | JBoss                               |       2 |              |           | t
  3003 | MySQL                               |       1 |              |           | t
  3004 | WebSphere                           |       2 |              |           | t
  4000 | Microsoft Exchange Server 2003      |       3 |              |           | t
  4001 | Exchange Server 2007 /2010          |       3 |              |           | t
  4003 | Microsoft SQL Server 2008           |       1 |              |           | t
  4004 | Microsoft ISA Server 2006           |      99 |              |           | t
  4005 | Microsoft IIS                       |       4 |              |           | t
  3005 | DB2                                 |       1 |              |           | t
  3006 | Apache HTTP Server                  |       4 |              |           | t
  3007 | Oracle                              |       1 |              |           | t
  3008 | PostgreSQL                          |       1 |              |           | t
  3009 | WebLogic                            |       2 |              |           | t
  3010 | Adobe ColdFusion                    |       2 |              |           | t
  3011 | Sybase                              |       1 |              |           | t
  4007 | Microsoft SQL Server 2005 (EXPRESS) |       1 |              |           | t
  4008 | Microsoft Team Foundation Server    |       2 |              |           | t
  4009 | Microsoft .NET                      |      99 |              |           | t
  3012 | Apache Tomcat                       |       2 |              |           | f
```

Apache Tomcat repeats 2 times when this table shown in an dropdown. How do I disable the last row which is 3012? I have an option to delete it but this table is used in several places so I don't want to delete it.

Comment: Way too little information to go on here. It could be as simple as "WHERE appid!=3012", but who the hell knows?

Comment: @ ceejayoz : when i use this then my whole dropdown is shown empty

Comment: i already use this ... $query = "select appid,appname from stat_applications where appid!=0 and appid!=1000";now where i can put this

Comment: @ ceejayoz: after solve this also put ur coment in ans i want to select ur ans as best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the more important question is why is it in your database twice. Depending on what you're using this query for ignoring one could be just as wrong as deleting one. Maybe it has somehting to do with that being the only entry with display f. I guess you could just do WHERE display != 'f'

Comment: $query = "select appid,appname from stat_applications where appid!=0 and appid!=1000";now where i can put this –

Comment: at the end - `... and appid!=1000 and display != 'f'`

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat appears twice because it's in the table twice, once with ID 3001 and again with ID 3012.  I'd call that a problem with the data, not with the query.  Does it really need to be there twice?  You say you're reluctant to delete one of them because it's used in several places, but if you don't fix it now, it'll only be harder to fix later.

I'd focus on merging those duplicate rows.  Find all the records (in other tables) that refer to one of this pair, and update them to refer to the other one instead.  Then you can delete the one that nothing refers to anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `display` column? Sounds like it is for filtering out things that are not supposed to be shown. So, you could do a query like this:

```
SELECT appid, appname
FROM stat_applications
WHERE appid  <> 0
  AND appid  <> 1000
  AND display = 't'
```

If you don't want to use `display`, then you could just add 3012 to your list of things to ignore:

```
SELECT appid, appname
FROM stat_applications
WHERE appid  <> 0
  AND appid  <> 1000
  AND appid  <> 3012
```

Or, since your exclusion list is getting longer, use `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT appid, appname
FROM stat_applications
WHERE appid NOT IN (0, 1000, 3012)
```